# How to make an ungeneric class extending from a generic super class

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am willing to add Strings into a List which is only allowed to contain Strings. After calling `add(String s)`, I would like to modify the string (e.g.: add the date) and then store the modified String into the List. However, It is necessary that other data types cannot be added.

My first idea is to extend from a simple ArrayList. Unfortunately, I would end up having to modify about 7-12 functions.

What would your suggestions be?

Thanks

Comment: `class B extends ArrayList<String>`. You almost certainly don't *actually* want this.

Comment: I suggest you implement an interface instead: `class B implements List<String>`.

Comment: I want this. Because I have to rewrite the add-method, where to each String I want to add the recent Date needs to be added as a String... All others methods shall work like ArrayList...
What would you suggest instead?

Comment: You rather want to implement `List<String>` and use an `ArrayList<String>` as a member variable, adapter pattern. Extending `ArrayList<String>` sounds scary.

Comment: If you’re planning to alter every added element, you’ll need to override more than the `add` methods.  You also need to override addAll, set, replaceAll, subList, and listIterator.  A far better option is to create your own class which extends nothing (other than java.lang.Object), keeps a private List<String>, and provides some public methods to read and modify it.  A public method that provides a *defensive copy* of the List is probably a good idea.

Comment: I accept this as a far better solution. I am sorry (I am studying in the first semester...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option I got suggested is to write a class which extends nothing, but java.lang.Object and then add a private ArrayList.

```
public class StringList {
   private ArrayList<String> list;
}
```

This method you can then easily be extended by an add function or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify that when you extend the array list that it is supplying `String` as the generic type and don't add a generic type to you new class.

```
public class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {...}
```

Comment: @tvsuchty check out this explanation of a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I'd say the two things that lead to the downvotes were the fact that it initially didn't say why you were trying to solve the issue with genetics and secondly there wasn't any indication of what you has tried and the problems you'd encountered in trying to solve the problem. Even so, for a first time poster I would personally say a down vote instead of a comment is a harsh easy to handle this!

Comment: Thank you! I will make it better in the next time.